# loop failing to break out upon validation

Tags: php, validation, loops

I have this same loop working with another piece of code, but I cannot figure out why my break is failing

code:

```
    unset($_SESSION['IPV6']);
    echo "<h4><br>I see that you just purchased a server and the domain '.$domain.',<br> there is still more work to be done.<br>";
    echo '<br>Here is your IPv4 Address  '.$_SESSION['IPV4'].'<br>';
    if(!empty($_SESSION['IPV6'])){
            echo 'Here is your IPv6 Address  '.$_SESSION['IPV6'].'<br>';
    }else{
            echo 'We had an issue getting your IPv6 address. One second while we attempt to retrieve it again<br>';
            for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++){
                    sleep(5);
                    echo 'here '.$x;
                    $server_output = getlist();
                    $decoded = json_decode($server_output, true);
                    foreach($decoded as $value) {
                            $ipdv6 = $value[0]['ip'];
                            var_dump($ipdv6);
                            echo '<br>';
                            if(!empty($ipdv6)){
                                    $_SESSION['IPV6'] = $ipdv6;
                                    echo 'Here is yourr IPv6 Address  '.$_SESSION['IPV6'].'<br>';
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

output:

```
I see that you just purchased a server and the domain '.nyc3.com.',
there is still more work to be done.

Here is your IPv4 Address 104.156.233.72
We had an issue getting your IPv6 address. One second while we attempt to retrieve it again
here 0string(39) "2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d" 
Here is yourr IPv6 Address 2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d
here 1string(39) "2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d" 
Here is yourr IPv6 Address 2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d
here 2string(39) "2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d" 
Here is yourr IPv6 Address 2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d
here 3string(39) "2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d" 
Here is yourr IPv6 Address 2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d
here 4string(39) "2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d" 
Here is yourr IPv6 Address 2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d
here 5string(39) "2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d" 
Here is yourr IPv6 Address 2001:19f0:5800:8b63:5400:00ff:fe08:da5d
```

How do I break out of my loop upon validation if(!empty($ipdv6)) ??

Comment: You have two loops - are you trying to break out of the `for` loop, instead of just the foreach loop?

Comment: @andrewsi  break out of both.

Comment: Have a look at the man page: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php - `break` can take a parameter to say how many layers of loop you want to break out of. So in this case `break 2` should work.

Comment: But bear in mind that doing this sort of thing makes your code that much harder to maintain.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, @andrewsi

Comment: @andrewsi  yes, post that as an answer. I did not know about that little trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` will break out of the loop that you're currently in; a simplified version of your code is:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++){
    foreach($decoded as $value) {
        if(!empty($ipdv6)){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So your `break` will exit the `foreach` loop, returning control to the outer `for` loop.

[The manual page for break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) says that it can take an optional parameter, which is how many levels of loop to break out of; in this case:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++){
    foreach($decoded as $value) {
        if(!empty($ipdv6)){
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

will break out of both loops.

Bear in mind that doing this makes your code that much more difficult to maintain - I'm a big fan of writing code that I can understand quickly when I come back to re-read it six months later, and this isn't something I find especially intuitive.